# Che differenza c'è fra "panino" e "tramezzino" in Italiano?

Tags: word-meaning, difference

In English, both words translate into "sandwich". But there has to be a difference between the two words. Does "tramezzino" means "smaller sandwich" ("tra"-"mezzino")?

Me lo spiegate, per favore? Grazie!

Answer (score 6):

**Panino** is usually a small shaped bread. For extension, with the term panino can be also indicated a filled roll, which is a loaf of bread horizontally sliced and filled with various good stuff, like ham, mozzarella and so on.

Conversely the **tramezzino** is triangularly shaped and it is made of two slices of sandwich bread (we call it ***pancarrè***) filled with cured meat, cheese, vegetables or others.

From Wikipedia:

> The [tramezzino](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tramezzino) is a usually triangular sandwich constructed from two
>   slices of soft white bread, with the crusts removed. Tramezzini are
>   popular and inexpensive snack sandwiches available at many Italian
>   bars throughout the day. Popular fillings include tuna, olive, and
>   prosciutto, but many other fillings can be used.
>
> The origin of the tramezzino can be found in the Caffè Mulassano di
>   Piazza Castello in Turin, where it was devised in 1925 as an
>   alternative to English tea sandwiches.
>
> The word tramezzino was invented by [Gabriele D'Annunzio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gabriele_D%27Annunzio) (a famous Italian 
>   writer and poet) as a
>   replacement for the English word "sandwich". Tramezzino is the
>   diminutive of the word tramezzo with the addition of the suffix -ino,
>   meant as a half-way between breakfast and lunch, where to eat a
>   break-hungry snack.

Answer (score 1):

[Tramezzino](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tramezzino) is made with toast bread or white bread and usually have triangular form.

Sandwich in Italy is used for "baguette style sandwich"

Panino is the generic word for anything else

The name Tramezzino derive from [tramezzo](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/tramezzo/) that is the divider wall in houses and suggest the time between breakfast and lunch

Comment: Grazie per l'informazione. :)